# Unexpected node type: EXPR found when expecting type: LABELED_ARG

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run my code in android device. But i am getting this error :

```
Build file '/Users/sathish/Documents/WorkSpace/RN/mealMate/android/app/build.gradle' line: 83

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/sathish/Documents/WorkSpace/RN/mealMate/android/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/sathish/Documents/WorkSpace/RN/mealMate/android/app/build.gradle': 83: Unexpected node type: EXPR found when expecting type: LABELED_ARG at line: 83 column: 5. File: _BuildScript_ @ line 83, column 5.
         set('react-native', [
         ^

  1 error
```

my `build.gradle` :

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    set('react-native', [
    versions: [
      // Overriding Build/Android SDK Versions
      android : [
        minSdk    : 16,
        targetSdk : 28,
        compileSdk: 28,
      ],

      // Overriding Library SDK Versions
      firebase: [
        // Override Firebase SDK Version
        bom           : "21.1.0",

        // Override Crashlytics SDK Version
        crashlytics   : "2.10.0",

        // Override Crashlytics SDK Version
        crashlyticsNdk: "2.1.0"
      ],
    ],
  ])
]
```

Not sure whats wrong with my  set('react-native', [.

Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems in your code, If you want to override firebase android SDK in react-native, your code should be like this :

**/android/app/build.gradle** :

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]
```

**/android/build.gradle** :

```
project.ext["react-native"] = [
    versions: [
      // Overriding Build/Android SDK Versions
      android : [
        minSdk    : 16,
        targetSdk : 28,
        compileSdk: 28,
      ],

      // Overriding Library SDK Versions
      firebase: [
        // Override Firebase SDK Version
        bom           : "21.1.0",

        // Override Crashlytics SDK Version
        crashlytics   : "2.10.0",

        // Override Crashlytics SDK Version
        crashlyticsNdk: "2.1.0"
      ],
    ],
]
```